# While loading a script dynamically using js, why do we use callback when we have the onload event?

Tags: javascript

What I need to do is load a script at https://www.myscripturl.com/script.js/ using javascript
I found this piece of code in one of the answers in stackoverflow:

```js
function loadscript(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://www.myscripturl.com/script.js/";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  script.onload = function() {
    callback()
  };

}

function myFunction() {
  // Scripts are loaded, do anything here
}

loadscript(myFunction);
```

The thing is why do we need to use callback when it performs the same just using the onload event.

Comment: What do you mean? If you do not call the calback, myFunction will not be executed. If you move the content of myFunction into the onload function you do not need a separate function. Also you can now do just this: `script.onload=myFunction;` and have `loadScript()` without passing a callback but then you cannot call loadScript with another function as you can now

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, I was talking about what you just said, I was doing this: script.onload=myFunction; Alright, so I wont be able to call that function again.. Thanks

Comment: You should not call a loadscript more than once. If you need to execute the script again, just do myFunction() if the script is already loaded. I did not notice that your loadScript only loads the same script  and not different scripts passed to it as in `loadScript("myScript.js",myFunction)` for example

Comment: Okay.. Thanks :)